# Join Query on Datetime field

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to write the query  based on the below condition.

I have two tables , in that i need to fetch the all the columns from table1 and one more column from another field based on the date field.
`Date 1` field in `Table 1` is in `Datetime` format,
`Date2` field in `table 2` id in `date` Format.

I am assuming the below query , please update me is there any changes

```
Select Table1.*, c3 
From Table1
Full Outer join
Table2 
On Date(Date1) = Date2
```

- here I'm using the Date function to convert the datetime field to date format.
- C3 is column in Table 2.

**Please confirm me which join i should use?**

Comment: So, what exactly is the question?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins?rq=1 It will answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ON` clause looks correct. Your specification seems to call for a `JOIN` (inner join) or a `LEFT JOIN`.  MySQL doesn't have `FULL OUTER JOIN`. In any rate it probably doesn't make sense for your application. (But that's a guess on my part.)

Try this.

```
       SELECT t1.*, t2.c3
         FROM Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON Date(t1.Date1) = t.Date2
```

That will give you every row in Table1, and the associated `c3` values from Table2.  If any given row in Table1 lacks a corresponding row in Table2, you'll get a NULL for the `c3` value (that's what LEFT JOIN does).